# Setting jquery chosen options unsorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-chosen

Any one know if there's a way to set the chosen options unsorted when the values are integer?

I currently have a chosen to select the days of the week filled with the following JSON

```
[{"VAL":1,"DES":"Sunday","$$hashKey":"object:611"},
{"VAL":2,"DES":"Monday","$$hashKey":"object:612"},
{"VAL":3,"DES":"Tuesday","$$hashKey":"object:613"},
{"VAL":4,"DES":"Wednesday","$$hashKey":"object:614"},
{"VAL":5,"DES":"Thursday","$$hashKey":"object:615"},
{"VAL":6,"DES":"Friday","$$hashKey":"object:616"},
{"VAL":7,"DES":"Saturday","$$hashKey":"object:617"}]
```

And, when I select Wednesday first, and then Sunday, I would expect to be listed as Wednesday, Sunday ([4, 1]) instead of the sorted way, Sunday, Wednesday ([1, 4])

You can see the issue in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teoyz4no/1/). Just try to select first wednesday and then monday, see how it's sorted

For better context, I'm using [adityasharat angular chosen directive](http://adityasharat.github.io/angular-chosen/) which uses [jQuery chosen plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Thanks

Edit: Just for the kick of it, I [tested the chosen plugin alone](https://jsfiddle.net/dryehr7w/), and it's setting the values unsorted, as I wish them to be listed. But I can't use pure jquery, as I'm trying to stick to angular

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Natural Sorting in ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166802/how-to-use-natural-sorting-in-ng-options)

Comment: @Rastalamm yeah, I don't think it's te same issue. See, I want my chosen options to be set on the chosen order, not ordered by it's value, so I can have [4, 1, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5]